# WoW Classic API Event for Addon Messages?

Tags: lua, world-of-warcraft

I am developing a WoW classic addon and want to send a message via `C_ChatInfo.SendAddonMessage` upon player login to sync some data with other players that have the addon. I tied this sync process to the event `PLAYER_LOGIN` (I also tried `PLAYER_ENTERING_WORLD`), but it appears I am getting a `success = false` return from the `C_ChatInfo.SendAddonMessage`. If I use `/console ReloadUI` , this works perfectly and the addon message is sent. Is there some event I can use to know that addon messages are enabled? What other reason might there be for a message to fail upon normal log in, but work after reload ui?

Comment: Don't call SendAddonMessage directly. Use a library to do it for you. The libraries will handle checking for if the player hasn't fully logged in yet and delay sending the message.

Comment: I've tried [ChatThrottleLib](https://www.wowinterface.com/downloads/info5207-ChatThrottleLib.html) and I have the same issue. Do you know of a specific classic library which delays sending until the character is logged in?

Comment: forgot to tag @Teelo?

Comment: Use AceComm https://www.wowace.com/projects/ace3/pages/api/ace-comm-3-0